# Postgresql vector search according to word apppearance

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

Let's set the **context first**:

- Our database is postgres 8.4.20
- My table contains a very large list of full names.
- These names can only be in ONE column.
- We are using vectors to search through this table.
- We require fast searchs.

**Now the problem**:
I can search through the entire table really fast and it seems to be working as intended. The problem raises when the subject you are searching for has 2 last names like:

- Ramón Flores Flores
- Ernesto Morales Morales

  In this particular case it will bring every record in the database containing "Ramón Flores" or "Ernesto Morales".

What im looking for is to be able to bring ONLY the records that contains "Ramón Flores Flores" or "Ernesto Morales Morales".
What I'm thinking is to create another column containing stats of each record and add some WHERE clause to select ONLY if each word appears only once.

Thanks in advance :)

**[edit] Progress note #1:**
Well, im trying **ts_rank** to give those results some sense and then im using a WHERE clause > 0.1. While is helping me to narrow those results down this is not a full solution yet.
I'll keep researching :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While **ts_rank** offers some kind of an alternative to deal with this... it seems to be impossible to achive what I'm trying to achieve using postgres only.

**ts_rank** behaves somehow weird when we face a string with 2 or 3 identical words (once you "vectorize" them; if that's even a word) so, at the end of the day you need to compare those strings and use diffrent **ts_rank** rules when you find these 2 or 3 identical words.

My main program is written in PHP so I ended up using that layer to compare my words and use the right rule.

I'm still hoping for someone to help me find a better way.